# How to filter with Linq

Tags: .net, linq

My Log class has 2 properties.

```
List<LogDetails>
string Title
```

And my LogDetails class has 2 properties:

```
string Message
LogStatus LogStatus  //enum
```

During this objects life time, it receives many messages which are stored for logging at a later stage. The LogStatus Enum has a few states, but simply it is either "in progress", "file not found error", "success" or "failed".

I am trying to use Linq to match only those which failed, but I can't build the new type.

```
List<Log> filteredLogs = (from a in logs
                          from b in a.LogDetailsList
                          where b.Status == LogDetails.LogStatus.Failed
                          select new Log()
                                  {
                                     Title = a.Title,
                                     LogDetailsList = a.LogDetailsList
                                  }).Distinct().ToList();
```

My filteredLogs returns to me the full list as if the where clause hadn't worked.

I tried

```
 List<Log> filteredLogs = (from a in logs
                           from b in a.LogDetailsList
                           where b.Status == LogDetails.LogStatus.Failed
                           select new Log()
                                  {
                                       Title = a.Title,
                                       LogDetailsList = new LogDetails() { Message = b.Message, Status = b.Status }
                                  }).Distinct().ToList();
```

This doesn't work either as it appears I can't call the ToList() method from within the Linq query.

**EDIT**

Does any one have any suggestions on how to overcome this issue? My goal is to have a List which only lists those which failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Any` on your "nested" `LogDetails` list.

```
List<Log> failedLogs = logs
            .Where(l => l.LogDetails.Any(ld => ld.LogStatus==LogStatus.Failed))
            .ToList();
```

This returns all logs where at least one log-detail has `LogStatus.Failed`.

Here's a [**Demo**](http://ideone.com/AJsC0M).

Comment: Did you have to make it look so easy! :) I've not used Any before so I will research.

Comment: @DaveRook: The query above retuns only those logs with one or multiple log-details which `LogStatus` is `LogStatus.Failed`. Are you looking for that logs where all details are failed instead?

Comment: Yes please. I'm only after those which failed, nothing else.

Comment: @DaveRook: Added a demo to show you that it works. That demo has two logs but only one has a logdetail with `LogStatus=LogStatus.Failed`. Do you want only these details as property of the logs? So instead of three details in my demo just one(the one which failed)?

Comment: Oh, I now get it! I'm sorry Tim, you were of course right with the above, the demo is amazing and really helped it to sync in. I'm sorry, I couldn't see the wood for the trees! Thank you